# upgrade apache cassandra from 2.0.11 to 3.11

Tags: cassandra, upgrade, cassandra-3.0

What should be the upgrade path of Apache Cassandra 2.0.11 to 3.11 (latest)?

My node ring is 4 machines with around 400 GB.

Answer (score 4):

you can upgrade from Cassandra 2.1.9 (or higher) to Cassandra 3.11 (or higher).However here you may need to go to through with intermediate upgrade.

`2.0.11 -> 2.2.* -> 3.11`

Steps for upgrade cassandra version

1.Take snapshots on each node

2.Run nodetool drain

3.Stop cassandra services.

4.Back up your Cassandra configuration files from the old installation to safe place.

5.Update java version to 8 if required

6.Install the binaries (via tarball, apt-get, yum, etc...) for the apache Cassandra.

Configure the new product.
Compare, merge and update any modifications you have previously made into the new configuration files for the apache version (cassandra.yaml, cassandra-env.sh, etc.).

7.Start the cassandra services.

8.Check the logs for warnings, errors, and exceptions. tail -f /var/logs/cassandra/system.log # or path where you set your logs.
Run nodetool upgradesstables

9."nodetool upgradesstables" (The upgradesstables step can be run on each node after the nodes done with migration.)
Check the logs for warnings, errors, and exceptions. tail -f /var/logs/cassandra/system.log # or path where you set your logs.

10.Check cassandra version "nodetool version".

Comment: can 2.0.11 live together with 3.11 on the same ring?

Comment: No, you can not

Comment: will export the data to dumpfile\csv ,remove and install new version and then  restore it to a new version will be faster (500gb per server) ?

Comment: what complication you have in upgrade ?

Comment: wondering you want to chose csv import and export over upgrade ?

Comment: my question si if it will be simpler to export to csv and import it to a newer version